# Sequence of random variables, mean zero, convergence to -infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables, independence, law-of-large-numbers

> What would be an example of a sequence $(X_k)$ of independent random variables with zero mean such that
>   $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} \xrightarrow[\mbox{almost surely}]{n \to \infty}-\infty\ ?$$

My thoughts:

I guess this is supposed to be a counterexample to the strong law of large numbers. I know that the variance of my sequence needs to be unbounded, because otherwise that sequence would fulfill all conditions of the SLLN.
I have found both, sequences that fulfill independency and sequences that fulfill the second condition, but i could not imagine any sequence that fulfills both of them. One idea was to use the Cantor, but I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: The idea is to make the expectations irrelevant to the almost sure behaviour, consider for example the distributions $P(X_n=n^2)=1/(n^2+1)$, $P(X_n=-1)=n^2//(n^2+1)$.

Comment: oh sorry, i've made a mistake in my formula, N is not fix, there should be n instead. I'm going to fix that now.

Comment: with this change, I don't see how the expression above converges to minus infinity with your sequence of random variables.

Comment: OK then $P(X_n=n^3)=1/(n^2+1)$, $P(X_n=-n)=n^2/(n^2+1)$.

Comment: It might be a bit easier to actually perform the calculation by adopting exponential tail behavior. For example you could do $P(X_n=-2^n)=1-2^{-n},P(X_n=4^n)=2^{-n}-4^{-n},P(X_n=0)=4^{-n}$. I think this makes it so you can handle the relevant series explicitly.

Comment: @Did Ok, thanks for your fast answer. I'm now trying to prove convergence a.s. of your example; may i'll still need some help later with that :)

Comment: @Ian: Thanks a lot, your example seems a little bit more beautiful... but i'm struggling to show convergence a.s.... i've only done it for quite simple examples so far....

Comment: Hint: Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: That would be optimal.